# What is Slimer a ghost of?

Tags: ghostbusters

Throughout the Ghostbusters movies, the ghosts we see all appear to be ghosts of humans - with the exception of Slimer, which is a green blob with no legs and spindly arms.

[image]

What sort of creature (or human) was Slimer before he became a ghost?

Comment: Chris Christie joke in 3...2..

Comment: Ghost of my former cat...

Comment: Chris Christie joke!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Main canon

Dan Ackroyd [described him](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Slimer#cite_note-11) in the "making of" book as being *literally* the embodiment of the sloth and gluttony that you find within the walls of a swanky hotel. It stands to reason that he didn't exist (e.g. he's not the ghost *of* anything) until he came into being:

> "So, in reading the literature and reading about full head and torso
>   apparitions, I found out that it is very rare that you see a full
>   figure -- it is usually just a hint of the former being. **The Onionhead
>   is a vapor -- a kind of confluence of stored up psychic energy. He's
>   an accumulation of spirits that haunt this hotel,** and he just doesn't
>   want to leave."

### Just for fun

Both Ackroyd and Joe Medjuck have stated in various interviews that Slimer is the ghost of their long-time friend John Belushi. Again, to quote from the "[making of](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Slimer#cite_note-11)" book;

> One day, during preproduction, we were all sitting around talking
>   about the Onionhead concept, and Ivan remarked that the character was
>   sort of like Bluto in Animal House -- like the ghost of John Belushi,
>   in a way, Danny, who was obviously a good friend of John's, never
>   argued with that. Even so, **we never officially said that and we never
>   mentioned it in the script. It was just one way to look at the
>   character, because Onionhead's grossness is like Bluto's in Animal
>   House. We certainly never expected anyone to recognize him as such,
>   although somehow the word did get out and we received some calls from
>   a few newspapers saying they'd heard we had the ghost of John Belushi
>   in our movie.**

Comment: "and he just doesn't want to leave" until he becomes a bus driver!

Comment: @colmde - that was pretty funny.